# what do the numbers mean in ip rule show command

Tags: networking, ip, iproute

If I type `ip rule show` command in my machine, I get the output as,

```
0:  from all lookup local 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

What do the numbers **0**,**32766** and **32767** mean?

I do understand these are some priorities and **0** is special priority and cannot be deleted.

Also, if I add a new policy it will be created with a priority as **32765**. Is my understanding correct?

Also, I see some information regarding priority for `ip rule add` from [here](http://homepage.smc.edu/morgan_david/cs70/ip-cref.pdf).

> Really, for historical reasons ip rule add does not require a priority
>   value and allows them to be non-unique. If the user does not supplied
>   a priority, it is selected by the kernel. If the user creates a rule
>   with a priority value that already exists, the kernel does not reject
>   the request. It adds the new rule before all old rules of the same
>   priority. It is mistake in design, nomore. And it will be fixed one
>   day, so do not rely on this feature. Use explicit priorities.

Comment: take a look in man `ip-rule`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the man page [`ip-rule`](http://www.dsm.fordham.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi.pl?topic=ip-rule&ampsect=8):

> At startup time the kernel configures the default RPDB consisting of three 
>   rules:
>
> ```
>    1.  Priority: 0, Selector: match anything, Action: lookup routing 
>        table local (ID 255).  The local table is a special routing table 
>        containing high priority control routes for local and broadcast 
>        addresses.
>
>        Rule 0 is special. It cannot be deleted or overridden.
>
>    2.  Priority: 32766, Selector: match anything, Action: lookup routing 
>        table main (ID 254).  The main table is the normal routing table 
>        containing all non-policy routes. This rule may be deleted and/or 
>        overridden with other ones by the administrator.
>
>    3.  Priority: 32767, Selector: match anything, Action: lookup routing 
>        table default (ID 253).  The default table is empty.  It is 
>        reserved for some post-processing if no previous default rules 
>        selected the packet.  This rule may also be deleted.
>
>   Each RPDB entry has additional attributes.  F.e. each rule has a pointer 
>   to some routing table.  NAT and masquerading rules have an attribute to 
>   select new IP address to translate/masquerade.  Besides that, rules have 
>   some optional attributes, which routes have, namely realms.  These 
>   values do not override those contained in the routing tables.  They are 
>   only used if the route did not select any attributes.
> ```

So those numbers, 0, 32766, and 32767 are the priority that the rules will get be applied.

**NOTE:** The other numbers mentioned above: 255, 254, and 253 correspond to the routing tables as described in this file:

```
$ more /etc/iproute2/rt_tables 
#
# reserved values
#
255 local
254 main
253 default
0   unspec
#
# local
#
#1  inr.ruhep
```

The names above can then be used when querying the routing tables like so:

```
$ ip route show table local
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 172.17.0.0 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.42.1 
local 172.17.42.1 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope host  src 172.17.42.1 
broadcast 172.17.255.255 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.42.1 
broadcast 192.168.1.0 dev wlp1s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.80 
local 192.168.1.80 dev wlp1s0  proto kernel  scope host  src 192.168.1.80 
broadcast 192.168.1.255 dev wlp1s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.80
```

#### References

- [iproute2 project page](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/iproute2)
- [iproute2 Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iproute2)